# How to get file's "Stationary Pad" flag information using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to check for "Stationary Pad" flag of a file but I am not getting any way to read this information.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: I am using following code to get fileCreationDate. Similarly i want to check "Stationary Pad" flag of a file.
 
NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:////     error:nil];
NSDate *result = [fileAttribs fileCreationDate];

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Carbon File Manager API to do this, you can't do it from Cocoa. That said, this code does still work in the Xcode 12 beta.

```
-(BOOL)isStationaryPad:(NSString *)path
{
    static kIsStationary = 0x0800;
    CFURLRef url;
    FSRef fsRef;
    FSCatalogInfo catInfo;
    BOOL success;
    url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, FALSE);
    if (!url) return NO;
    success = CFURLGetFSRef(url, &fsRef);
    CFRelease(url);
    //  catalog info from file system reference; isStationary status from catalog info
    if (success && (FSGetCatalogInfo(&fsRef, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &catInfo, nil, nil, nil))==noErr)
    { 
        return ((((FileInfo*)catInfo.finderInfo)->finderFlags & kIsStationary) == kIsStationary);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This code is from the [open source version of the Bean](https://github.com/iamleeg/NewBean) word processor.

Comment: thanks for posting your answer. Unfortunately FSGetCatalogInfo is deprecated and I don't want to use deprecated API, that is why looking for another approach.